# SQL How to check if column exists before inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

I need to migrate company emails into user emails

```
INSERT INTO public.user_emails ( SELECT DISTINCT
    ar. "userId",
    c. "companyEmail"
FROM
    public.companies AS c
    INNER JOIN public.account_roles AS ar ON c.id = ar. "companyId"
        AND ar. "employeeId" IS NULL
WHERE
    ar. "userId" NOT IN (
        SELECT
            "userId"
        FROM
            public.user_emails));
```

At the moment I get this error:

> [ERROR] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: column c.companyEmail does not exist

How can I add `IF EXISTS` or `CASE` logic here to check if `c.companyEmail` exists?

Comment: It will be very bad practice to mix DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: `INSERT INTO public.user_emails ( col1, col2, col3, ...) SELECT DISTINCT
    ar. "userId",
    c. "companyEmail"`

Comment: Why don't you know what columns are in the tables you are querying?  I think there is a more fundamental problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems postgresql does have this statement.

```
ALTER TABLE companies 
  ADD companyEmail IF NOT EXISTS companyEmail varchar(32);
```

Then after this you can run the insert sql.

But again, this is not recommended. DDL and DML should be run with different roles, the role to insert should not have permission to change table structure.

Answer (score -2):

which kind of database?
if mysql, you can try INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY